# Add a class to <img> element of thumbnail of "favorites", which is a plugin of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add classes to `<img>` images and add `%.hich` file and where should I change?

Comment: I would recommend that you contact the developers (through github/their web site/support forum or something). SO is for when you're having problems with _your_ code. It's not a support for third party libraries.